# How can I make a link from content profile node to it's user account page?

Tags: 6, users

I'm trying to find out how to make a direct link from content profile node view/edit page to it's account page.

As an admin role when I check somebody's profile node I sometimes also  need to check his/her account. So it would be much easier if I can make a direct link.

I need this link to be visible only to Admin role. Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and easy/dirty on the view page at least, in your node template for your content profile type, let's assume it is `node-profile.tpl.php`, you could add something like

```
<?php if (user_access('administer users') && $page): ?>
  <?php print l('User Account For This Profile', 'user/' . $node->uid);
<?php endif; ?>
```

wherever you wanted that link.  If you want it on the teasers of the node as well, eg, if the profiles are listed in a view or on the front page, etc, just take out the `&& $page` otherwise this will only show up in the full node pages.  You can also pick any permission you want, I just grabbed the first one that made sense to me :)

ADDITION:  if you actually have a role called 'Admin' you can check for it like this:

```
 <?php 
   global $user;
   if (in_array('Admin',array_values($user->roles)) && $page) {
      print l('User Account For This Profile', 'user/' . $node->uid);
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: and if you don't have node templates for individual types, just add `$node->type=='profile' &&` into the `if` :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It perfectly works for my need :)