# How can I make a link from user account page to its content profile node?

Tags: 6, users

I could make a link from content profile to its user page by [this method](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37284/how-can-i-make-a-link-from-content-profile-node-to-its-user-account-page/37298#37298).

But how can I do the other way round from user account page to content profile?

Answer (score 0):

Probably [content_profile_load](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!content_profile!content_profile.module/function/content_profile_load/6) is the way to go.

The relevant issue here : http://drupal.org/node/680356